# How to apply get_group to groupby data in pandas when the groupby column is a category

Tags: pandas

```
age_cleaned_titanic_df.groupby('Age_group').mean()
age_cleaned_titanic_df.groupby('Age_group').get_group((0,10])
```

The get_group function gives me errors as the 'Age_group' column has values which are half-open indices of bins. 
(0,10]
(10,20]
...
...
(70,80].

How do I then perform the get_group() method? Most of the examples in the documentation and stackoverflow talk about columns values which are strings/numbers where get_group() becomes straightforward. How to do it when the groupby column is a category?

Comment: did you try `age_cleaned_titanic_df.groupby('Age_group').get_group('(0,10]')`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It gives a key error: `KeyError: '(0,10]'`

Comment: what about `age_cleaned_titanic_df.groupby('Age_group').get_group('(0, 10]')`? [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples/32536193#32536193)

Comment: You will have to provide a reproducible example (some runnable code that shows the problem), as normally `get_group` should work fine with categoricals (also show your pandas version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there must be a space between `0,` and `10` - like `'(0, 10]'`.

Here is a small demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': np.random.randint(10,30,20)})
df['Age_group'] = pd.cut(df.age, bins=[10, 15, 20, 25, 30])
```

this works:

```
In [141]: df.groupby('Age_group').get_group('(10, 15]')
Out[141]:
    age Age_group
1    11  (10, 15]
6    12  (10, 15]
11   13  (10, 15]
12   14  (10, 15]
14   15  (10, 15]
15   12  (10, 15]
17   14  (10, 15]
18   13  (10, 15]
```

now the same, but without a white-space between values:

```
In [142]: df.groupby('Age_group').get_group('(10,15]')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-53b04eccd579> in <module>()
----> 1 df.groupby('Age_group').get_group('(10,15]')

...

KeyError: '(10,15]'
```

Data:

```
In [139]: df
Out[139]:
    age Age_group
0    25  (20, 25]
1    11  (10, 15]
2    27  (25, 30]
3    24  (20, 25]
4    27  (25, 30]
5    10       NaN
6    12  (10, 15]
7    20  (15, 20]
8    16  (15, 20]
9    29  (25, 30]
10   21  (20, 25]
11   13  (10, 15]
12   14  (10, 15]
13   21  (20, 25]
14   15  (10, 15]
15   12  (10, 15]
16   29  (25, 30]
17   14  (10, 15]
18   13  (10, 15]
19   19  (15, 20]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @maxU. This works brilliantly. Just tried it out. The space thing appears whimsical. Any idea what is the logic behind that?

Comment: @PradyutVatsa, that's just the way how the `pd.cut()` works - it creates bins as a strings